# How to run two sh files with ansible

Tags: macos, server, ansible

I have to .sh files, let's assume `file1.sh` and `file2.sh`. These two files run two servers. I want to start one server after another. I used the following command. But it didn't work.

```
- name: Starting Node 01
  script:
    cmd: ~/sample_ansible/00/bin/file1.sh
- name: Starting Node 02
  script:
    cmd: ~/sample_ansible/01/bin/file2.sh
```

This was the logs,

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: The logs indicate the second server is started after the first, what is wrong?

Comment: The server are not starting even the logs says so. That is the issue. How to run this command background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Issue solved]

The answer is: **Run the scripts background**

Insert the following code snippet to `/tasks/main.yml`

```
# Starting Node 01
- name: Starting Node 01
  shell: nohup ~/sample_ansible/00/bin/file1.sh &
# Starting Node 02
- name: Starting Node 02
  shell: nohup ~/sample_ansible/01/bin/file2.sh &
```